# Segmentation fault with fgets

Tags: c, heap-memory

I am doing a simple program just for opening a file and printing its contents line by line, but I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" while compiling with "gcc -o test pruebas.c" (my file is called pruebas.c) and then running the program in the Ubuntu Console from Windows 10, what could be the issue?

This is the code I wrote:

```
int main()
{
    char* line = NULL;
    FILE* file = fopen("D:/Documents/Uni/blur.lp", "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return(0);
```

(the ".lp" extension is the extension of an image format I have to develop for a homework)

Comment: You need to check `file` and make sure it's not NULL.

Comment: Try `char* line = NULL;` --> `char line[100];`

Comment: "Please read into this uninitialized pointer!" That's how programs crash. Remember C will not hold your hand and make sure everything is correct. You are 100% responsible for everything, including memory allocation and like how stensal points out, checking error conditions and reacting accordingly. Pay exceedingly close attention to little details and if stumped, **walk through in a debugger** to pin-point the problem.

Comment: What do you think `sizeof(line)` is?

Comment: The `fgets` function stores the read characters into space that you provided

Comment: You need to allocate memory for line before you use it.  Note that sizeof will only tell you the size of the pointer: not the size of the buffer you have allocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a improved version of your program that takes into account above comments.
It's also using preprocessor macros to define line size and file name:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 100
#define FILE_NAME "D:/Documents/Uni/blur.lp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char line[LINE_SIZE] ;
    FILE *file ;

    file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
      perror("cannot access " FILE_NAME);
      return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file))
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: This worked when running from CMD (windows 10), but I found that for running it on Ubuntu's console I had the path wrong, oops!